# Update order functionality not working in postgres with nestjs after updating existing enum values?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs

I have a `nestjs` application with `typeOrm` and `postgres` as db. I have hosted my database on `Vercel`. In this app, i have an order entity with some fields. I have a `status` column with an `enum` having the following values previously

- pending
- vendor
- dispatched

Later on, i added 2 more statuses in this enum by modifying my status column type named "order_status_enum" and added the following statuses

- delivered
- returned

Now, when i am trying to update the order status to any newly added statuses i.e returned, delivered so it throws this error

```
exception:  BadRequestException: Bad Request Exception
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at ValidationPipe.exceptionFactory 
(/home/ubuntu/servers/cwc- 
nest/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:99:20)
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at ValidationPipe.transform (/home/ubuntu/servers/cwc- 
nest/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:72:30)
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at resolveParamValue (/home/ubuntu/servers/cwc- 
nest/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:147:23)
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at pipesFn (/home/ubuntu/servers/cwc- 
nest/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:150:13)
0|cwc-nest-server  |     at /home/ubuntu/servers/cwc-                
nest/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:37:30 {
0|cwc-nest-server  |   response: {
0|cwc-nest-server  |     statusCode: 400,
0|cwc-nest-server  |     message: [ 'Invalud order status type' ],
0|cwc-nest-server  |     error: 'Bad Request'
0|cwc-nest-server  |   },
0|cwc-nest-server  |   status: 400,
0|cwc-nest-server  |   options: {}
0|cwc-nest-server  | }
0|cwc-nest-server  | request method: PUT request url/api/v1/orders/1             
request method: PUT request url/api/v1/orders/1 {"statusCode":400,"timestamp":"2023-12-27T20:47:37.094Z","path":"/api/v1/orders/1","method":"PUT","errorName":"BadRequestException","message":"Bad Request Exception"}
```

**Note: my enum type in vercel remote db is like this**

[image]

**Code:**

Now, here is my order entity

```
@Entity('orders')
export class Order extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({
    length: 500,
  })
  description: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  quantity: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  amount: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Customer, (customer) => customer.orders)
  customer: Customer;

  @OneToMany(() => OrderProduct, (orderProduct) => orderProduct.order, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  products: Array<OrderProduct>;


  @Column({
    nullable: false,
    type: 'enum',
    enum: OrderStatus,
    default: OrderStatus.PENDING,
  })
  status: OrderStatus;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Here is my `OrderStatus` enum

**Before Update:**

```
export enum OrderStatus {
  PENDING = 'pending',
  VENDOR = 'vendor',
  DISPATCHED = 'dispatched'
}
```

**After Update:**

```
export enum OrderStatus {
  PENDING = 'pending',
  VENDOR = 'vendor',
  DELIVERED = 'delivered',
  DISPATCHED = 'dispatched',
  RETURNED = 'returned',
}
```

Here is my `UpdateOrderDTO`

```
export class UpdateOrderDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Length(5, 400)
  @IsOptional()
  public description: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  @IsPositive()
  @IsOptional()
  public amount: number;


  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  public customerId: number;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => OrderProductDto)
  products: OrderProductDto[];


  @IsOptional()
  @IsEnum(OrderStatus, { message: 'Invalud order status type' })
  public status: OrderStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the above issue. The problem was that, i have deployed my nestjs application on `AWS EC2` instance. So, after updating the enum in the actual code what i did, i just stopped the server application with `pm2`, took the latest from the related branch, and then again restarted the application with `pm2`. The problem was that, the server application was using old metadata about that OrderStatusEnum, because i just pulled the latest code, but i didn't remove `dist` folder and build the application again. I resolved this issue with the following steps:

- On EC2 instance, stop nest app with `pm2`
- Pull the latest code from the relevant branch
- Build the nest app with `npm run build`
- Start the nest app again with `pm2`